# Recursive enumerable class or its complement?

Tags: turing-machines, recursively-enumerable

If `K = {<<M>> | L(M) has at least 1 word}`, then does K belong to the class of recursive enumerable (RE) languages or its complement?

I'm a bit confused, because if it is RE, then we'd have a TM W that semidecides it, but even for some language, `L(M)`, that does halt for at least a word, we don't know which word it is and may require a word with length tending to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{M_n\}$ and $\{W_n\}$ be recursive enumerations of the machines and the words. Now for each $n$  run $M_1\ldots M_n$ on $W_1\ldots W_n$ for $n$ steps, and output the code of the machines that stopped at some point. That produces a recursive enumeration of $K$.